# Mongoose populating refs inside refs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to save and retrieve a collection of game matches with associated games, and who played in it. My schema looks like this,

```
const TournamentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  matches: [{
    games: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
      ref: 'Game',
      players: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Player',
      }],
    }],
  }],
});
```

This is what the object in the database looks like,

```
{
    "__v": 0,
    "_id": "5a50ed6b267ddd32c4523327",
    "matches": [
        {
            "_id": "5a50ed6b267ddd32c4523328",
            "games": [
                {
                    "players": [
                        { "_id": "5a4fa908d9d55465ac4fdbe6" },
                        { "_id": "5a50cf3d09176c2bb0f98fe1" }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5a498918ffc6220edbe8a403"
                },
                {
                    "players": [
                        { "_id": "5a50cf5609176c2bb0f98fe2" },
                        { "_id": "5a50cf6009176c2bb0f98fe3" }
                    ],
                    "_id": "5a50cf9007c2bb0c73f3783a"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
}
```

I'm trying to retrieve it like this,

```
async function list(req, res, next) {
  logger.log('info', 'Incoming request to retrieve all tournaments');

  const tournaments = await Tournament.find().populate('matches.games.players');
  return res.json(tournaments);
}
```

However, what I get from the database is the same as what was saved. i.e the refs don't get resolved. If I change `type: Mixed` from `games` to `type: ObjectId` it wont persist `players`, but `populate` will resolve `games`. How do I work with refs inside refs?

As requested this is what my `Game` schema looks like,

```
const GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
  },
  scoring: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
    rank: {
      first_place: Number,
      second_place: Number,
      third_place: Number,
    },
  },
  max_num_players: Number,
  min_num_players: Number,
}, { runSettersOnQuery: true });
```

Each `Game` can have different `scoring` percentage per rank. For example for Counter Strike if you were first place, you would get 100% of points, second 80%, third 50%. However, for League of Legends first place would be 85%, second 60%, and third 50%.

Comment: I don't understand your schema, why do you store the game and players separately?  Shouldn't the players be inside the game schema? Can you describe the structure that you want to achieve? Want are the relationships between your schemas?

Comment: I have a collection of games and a collection of players. A tournament can have for example 4 matches. In the first match there's 4 games running at the same time with 3 players each (so 12 players in total). In the second match players switch around to play another game. Likewise all players must play a game once in the tournament. I'm trying to capture this scenario in the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you name "game" both the game definition in the game collection and the tournament game (which actually is game + players).

I would write the schema like this (not tested):

```
const TournamentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  matches: [{
    games: [{
      game: {
         type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
         ref: 'Game',
      },
      players: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Player',
      }],
    }],
  }],
});
```

And you would query like this:
   `Tournament.find().populate('matches.games.game matches.games.players')`

I still find unclear what the `Game` schema contains and why the `Game` itself does not have a list of players.

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you. About Game not having a list of Players - I thought I achieved this by putting an array of Player refs inside Game. The way I imagined this to work is an admin would populate Games, and Players register. Once registered the admin will create a tournament. Can you please expand on how you would implement this?

Comment: @syntaxerror Can you explain what your referenced `Game` schema contains? Do you have multiple game types? Because, a game can mean a game type (eg: League of Legends, Counter-Strike), or a game can mean a game (round) of a single game type (eg: all Games are League of Legends games). If it's the first case (where Game defines the game type) it makes sense that the tournament games contain both the game type and list of players. Can you post your game Schema (or part of it) in the question?

Comment: Yes, a `Game` schema captures a game type (League of Legends etc.. However, these are board games). A match is a round. In a round if there are 10 players, 3 could be playing League of Legends, 3 would play Counter Strike, 4 would play Rainbow Six, and 4 would play Call of Duty. In the next round players switch around. Rounds keep going until all players have played all the games. When a tournament begins players register themselves, and an Admin will create a tournament by selecting games that will be played today from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a bit late, but I'll share what I've understood through researching of a similar case of nested populating (as the title says).
In the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#deep-populate) it says that you could solve population across multiple levels in this way:
We have an Schema:

```
const CustomerSchema = new Schema({
  orders: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId || null,
      ref: "Order",
    },
  ],
(...)

})
```

But the orders at the same time have products refs:

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
products: {
    type: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" }],
  },
(...)
});
```

Now you could do a deep population like this:

```
const user = await CustomerModel.findById(id)
      .populate("user", "-password")
      .populate({ path: "orders", populate: { path: "products" } }) <---
      .exec();
```

Hope this might help someone with a similar case.